# Remove and insert php page with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

When a user clicks link i need to change the content of the page.

i tried this:

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "new content"
```

But this is only html.

How can i insert a php page with jquery?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Doing so will make your system extremely vulnerable to attacks, because javascript is run client-side, and therefore can be edited by the client.

Comment: ??? @DanielGelling People set new content for page elements all the time using JavaScript/jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [jQuery `load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
$( "#test" ).load( "some_file.php" );
```

This will load the contents of a PHP page into an element with an id of 'test'.

Comment: Thank you. this is working. One question. is there a way to load the content faster? because when i click the link the content shows afert 5 sec

Comment: It isn't the code that's slow, it is likely the connection @Kevinkuijer